# Identifying generating isometries of a wall paper group

Tags: group-theory, symmetric-groups, symmetry

I am currently revising for module exam on groups and symmetry. I can easily identify rotations, reflections, translations and glide reflections that preserve the wallpaper group. However I am struggling to see which of these isometries generate the wallpaper group. For example [wallpapergroup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wCHQZ.jpg)

I can see the translations , reflections, and glide reflections but the next question in the exam asks me to list a prove which isometries generate the wall paper group. How can I see/ know what generate the wallpaper group?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a nice [Patern Recognition Algorithm](https://www.google.at/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiNzo-z94zbAhVGy6QKHRf8CSMQFggqMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.math.toronto.edu%2Fdrorbn%2FGallery%2FSymmetry%2FTilings%2FSanderson%2FAlgorithm.pdf&usg=AOvVaw2ZiAizifrjqYlkZDcwrFGS) for identifying the wallpaper groups. It starts with the maximal rotation order, which can be $1,2,3,4,6$. The next question is, whether there is a mirror, or not; and so on. Once you know your wallpaper group, one can use a list of explicit generators of all $17$ groups, see [here](http://www-f1.ijs.si/~ziherl/Zavadlav12.pdf).